# Process monitoring CreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx

Tags: process, driver, monitoring

I'm developing a driver for monitoring process creation, I wrote a simple code to do it. I use the `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx`. But this doesn't work ! I exactly following Microsoft help [on this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559953%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
#include <ntddk.h>

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(
    IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject,  
    IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath
    );

VOID UnloadRoutine(
    IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject
    );

VOID CreateProcessNotifyEx(
    __inout   PEPROCESS Process,
    __in      HANDLE ProcessId,
    __in_opt  PPS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO CreateInfo
);



VOID CreateProcessNotifyEx(
    __inout   PEPROCESS Process,
    __in      HANDLE ProcessId,
    __in_opt  PPS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO CreateInfo

)
{
    if (CreateInfo)
    {
        if(CreateInfo->FileOpenNameAvailable==TRUE)
        {
            DbgPrintEx( 
                DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID,  
                DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL,
                "PID : 0x%X (%d)  ImageName :%wZ CmdLine : %wZ \n",
                ProcessId,ProcessId,
                CreateInfo->ImageFileName,
                CreateInfo->CommandLine
                );
        }
    }

}


VOID UnloadRoutine(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{
    PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx((PCREATE_PROCESS_NOTIFY_ROUTINE_EX)  CreateProcessNotifyEx, TRUE);
    DbgPrintEx( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID,  DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL,"Unloaded\n");
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject,  IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{

    NTSTATUS status = PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx((PCREATE_PROCESS_NOTIFY_ROUTINE_EX)CreateProcessNotifyEx, FALSE);
  if(!NT_SUCCESS(status))
  {
     DbgPrintEx( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID,  DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL,"Faild to PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx .status : 0x%X \n",status);
  }
    DriverObject->DriverUnload = UnloadRoutine;
     DbgPrintEx( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID,  DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL,"Load\n");

    return STATUS_SUCCESS; 

}
```

This drive load and run correctly but when run a program(new process), Doesn't happen any thing and can't register `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx` and i got `0xC0000022` Error (Access Denied).
[image]

Any idea ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Always i have to find my answer ;)

For passing this problem only need to add this value `LINKER_FLAGS=/integritycheck` to SOURCE file !

Before :

```
TARGETNAME=ProcView
TARGETPATH=.
TARGETTYPE=DRIVER

SOURCES=ProcView.c
```

Now :

```
TARGETNAME=ProcView
TARGETPATH=.
TARGETTYPE=DRIVER
LINKER_FLAGS=/integritycheck
SOURCES=ProcView.c
```

[image]