# i got the 100 errors when include a ntddk.h and wdm.h in my program

Tags: c++, windows

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWR1R.png)[2][this image shows the error]
I tried this code for block the process before execution.But i got a 100 errors while import a ntddk.h and wdm.h in c++.How to solve it?
Then i got sme erroe like this expected a ')' in my 14 and 22 line of code.
So what should i do for removing the 100 error?

```
#include <ntstatus.h>
#include<DbgEng.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <wdm.h>

int main()
{
    PEPROCESS process1;
    process1 = IoGetCurrentProcess();
    HANDLE ProcessId = PsGetCurrentProcessId();
    PS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO CreateInfo;
    PCREATE_PROCESS_NOTIFY_ROUTINE_EX(process1, ProcessId, CreateInfo);
    PCUNICODE_STRING ImageFileName;
    NTSTATUS  CreationStatus;
    CreateInfo.CreationStatus = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
    ImageFileName = CreateInfo.ImageFileName;
    if (ImageFileName == (PCUNICODE_STRING)L"firefox.exe")
    {
        NTSTATUS result;
        result = PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx(PCREATE_PROCESS_NOTIFY_ROUTINE_EX(process1, ProcessId, CreateInfo), FALSE);
        if (result)
        {
            printf("blocked");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then i got sme erroe like this expected a ')' in my 14 and 22 line of code.

```
PCREATE_PROCESS_NOTIFY_ROUTINE_EX(process1, ProcessId, CreateInfo);
result=PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx(PCREATE_PROCESS_NOTIFY_ROUTINE_EX(process1, ProcessId, CreateInfo), FALSE);
```

[this is the link for showing my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWR1R.png)

Comment: Could you provide some part of the unfiltered compiler error output? The first few errors should suffice. This might give more indication what the error cause is.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWR1R.png

Answer (score 3):

Don't mix SDK and DDK headers/libraries in one executable.

If you write a driver, don't include `Windows.h`. Driver code is not Win32 code.

If you want to create a process in suspended state from another Win32 process, use `CREATE_SUSPENDED` process creation flag in `CreateProcess()` (or a similar) Win32 call.

If you want to deny process creation for a particular process from a driver, check [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502929/process-monitoring-createprocessnotifyroutineex) for the boilerplate code.

Comment: I removed windows.h still errors are come in my program

Comment: yes i am writing a driver code.so what should i use instead of main().could you tell me the reason

Comment: could you tell how to block process creation.for example block the notepad.exe ,chrome.exe without using group policy.